# Couchbase .net client getting stuck in the constructor

Tags: .net, couchbase

I created this simple application

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Threading;
using Couchbase;
using Couchbase.Configuration;

namespace SimpleCouchClientTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple couch client test
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "http://localhost:8091/pools/";
            var bucketName = "testbucket";
            var bucketPassword = "testbucket";
            var numberOfLoops = 1000;

            for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfLoops; i++)
            {

                var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration
                {
                    Bucket = bucketName,
                    BucketPassword = bucketPassword,
                };

                config.Urls.Add(new Uri(connectionString));

                Console.WriteLine("Creating client #" + i);
                var couchClient = new CouchbaseClient(config);
                Console.WriteLine("Client #" + i + " created.");
                //Thread.Sleep(100); //-- uncomment this to run successfully
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `numberOfLoops` is set to 1000, and the CouchbaseClient creation hangs after first client. I ran the WinDbg session and I learnt the client is getting stuck on `BucketConfigListener.Start()`.

Is this a known issue? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and finally got this figured out. I was running fiddler2 to inspect the contents of the web requests/responses. However, that was interfering with the bucketsStreaming URI.

Once I closed out fiddler2 and made sure no other proxies were in place, it worked just fine. I was able to also reproduce the issue on demand by restarting fiddler2 before trying to initialize the constructor.

Let me know if that was what you were experiencing as well.

Comment: I do run Fiddler and that's an interesting point you made. But this is a production issue for me and we have a exclusive couchbase nodes. I may have to check with admins to figure out if there are any other proxies on that server. However, there is a bug logged on Couchbase for this https://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/NCBC-152#comment-77381

Comment: I read that thread and seems like the AVG issue would be proxy related as well - since I think AVG sets up a web proxy on the machine to intercept and analyze TCP traffic.

Also, instantiating the client 10,000 times will most likely overload the system as it has to keep 10,000 TCP sockets open concurrently, and leave them all active as it's using a streaming protocol. Normally in production you may only want/need to have as many static clients as you have buckets you are trying to reach.

Comment: Fiddler 2 screwed me up too. Never thought about it to be a culprit.

Comment: The most likely issue with proxies is that the client is failing to properly clean up resources and thus hits a connection pool (or similar) limit and blocks waiting for a connection that never becomes free. There's nothing that Fiddler or another proxy could do to fix this.

Comment: I had this problem with Fiddler and turned on the 'Stream' option in Fiddler's toolbar as per the advice on [this page](http://www.telerik.com/forums/fiddler-and-couchbase-client). It fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you trying to test/achieve by creating multiple client instances? I don't think you should create so many Couchbase clients. Its supposed to be one client instance serving all your app threads.

You should move "new CouchbaseClient(config);" outside of the loop.

e.g.

```
var config = new CouchbaseClientConfiguration
{
  Bucket = bucketName,
  BucketPassword = bucketPassword,
};
config.Urls.Add(new Uri(connectionString));
Console.WriteLine("Creating one client for all my app needs");
var couchClient = new CouchbaseClient(config);
for (var i = 0; i <= numberOfLoops; i++)
{
  // use client to do your test operations get/set/etc
}
```

Comment: This is only a test written to replicate the issue, we do not create so many clients in production, only 3-4 clients to serve different purposes. However, their creation gets stuck sometimes, and the problem seems to be stemming from the constructor itself.

Comment: Can you synchronize code block that create Couchbase client instance? So that you have only one instance of it? e.g. Singleton. Also check new upcoming .net client ver. 1.3.2: http://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/NCBC

Comment: How is synchronisation helpful in this loop? This is a single-threaded program. Even in production we do not have threads, we create different clients based on different configurations in a single loop.

Comment: I should have worded my previous comment a little nicely, sorry if it comes across as curt/rude.

Comment: Not a problem! We all here to help each other! I was talking about your production code. What kind of app is that, GUI or webapp? Can it use only one client? For example I have my wrapper classes that reuse the same couchbase client but each has diff. methods/rules to add/remove diff. document types.

Comment: My production code is a RESTful API, it is a wrapper, and I take configurations in an `List` and create different clients for different configurations.

Comment: ok, trying to understand use of it...so once you create a client instance based of requested cfg....what would be a use of it? Is each client instance points to a different couchbase cluster?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46274/discussion-between-babbupandey-and-user1697575)